# How to call setText() using a Float?

Tags: android, settext

i tried to call the setText() using the float but it dosnt seem to work can somone help me fix the problem?

```
public class Bmi extends MainActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bmi);
        final EditText h = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        final EditText w = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        final TextView r = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        Button calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                float height=0;
                float weight=0;
                float result=0;

                height= Float.parseFloat(h.getText().toString());
                weight= Float.parseFloat(w.getText().toString());

                result = (weight/(height * height));

                r.setText(result);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

im trying to make a simple bmi calculator just as practice but im having issues on making it work

Comment: r.setText("" + result);

Answer (score 2):

You should convert your float to a String by

```
r.setText(String.valueOf(result));
```

Or the quick and dirty way

```
r.setText("" + result);
```

If you want it localized (Dot or Comma seperated decimal number)

```
String text = NumberFormat.getInstance(YOURCONTEXT.getResources().getConfiguration().locale).format(result);
r.setText(text);
```

Just replace `YOURCONTEXT` with `MainActivity.this` if you are in the MainActivity or `getActivity()` if you are in a Fragment

If you want to set min or max fraction digits try this:

```
NumberFormat numberformat = NumberFormat.getInstance(YOURCONTEXT.getResources().getConfiguration().locale);
numberformat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
numberformat.setMaximumIntegerDigits(1);
numberformat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
String text = numberformat.format(result);
r.setText(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
r.setText(String.valueOf(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to display *float* value inside *TextView* you'll need to convert it to *String* first.

You can **convert any primitive data type(int, float, double,boolean,etc) to String by using String.valueOf(*value*)** method.

Here *value* is the variable which you want to convert to *String*.

You can use

```
String str = String.valueOf(result);
r.setText(str);
```

Alternatively

```
r.setText(String.valueOf(result));
```

Please comment if further help is required.